# How come I get a NSConcreteMutableData error when using a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

In my appdelegate, I set a couple instances of a custom NSObject (MemoryObject) and store them into an NSMutableDictionary:

```
- (void)setMObjects{
_radio = [[Memoryobject alloc]initWithName:@"Radio" andDescription:@"string" andImage:nil];
_fridge = [[Memoryobject alloc]initWithName:@"Fridge" andDescription:@"string" andImage:nil];

[_allMObjects setObject:_radio forKey:@"Radio"];
[_allMObjects setObject:_fridge forKey:@"Fridge"];
}
```

After that, I store them into the NSUserDefaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_allMObjects] forKey:@"neededMObjects"];
```

Then, in my ViewController, I want to retrieve this NSMutableDictionary:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
neededMObjects = [[defaults objectForKey:@"neededMObjects"] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"dict: %@", neededMObjects);
NSLog(@"object: %@", [neededMObjects objectForKey:@"neededMObjects"]);
```

The second NSLog gives me an error: -[NSConcreteMutableData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c32330

I don't understand this. Why is the error implying that I used NSConcreteMutableData, while I was using the NSMutableDictionary and why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting *the result of archiving the dictionary* into NSUserDefaults. The result of `archivedDataWithRootObject:` is an NSData. You need to unarchive it in order to get the dictionary back.